# Using a .NET-based ActiveX control in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6, activex

I have a C# .NET 4.5 user control that I need to make available to a legacy project in VB6.  (Part of a slow migration away from VB, but we can't do it all at once.)

I have been using a sample .NET-based, C# ActiveX control project from Microsoft from

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/csactivex-b86194f8

I can get the project to build and I can register the .DLL it creates on the target machine using regasm like

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe CSActiveX.ocx /codebase
```

and that registers without a problem.

However, when I look in VB I do not see the control as a component and when I try to "manually" add it by browsing to the control and adding it I get the error message

> The file XXXXXX is not registerable as an ActiveX component.

(Note I have been trying this, and the regasm step with the DLL using both a .DLL extension and a .OCX extension on the file.  I am not sure if that matters.  I get the same error either way.)

I am assuming that VB6 is giving me this error because the ActiveX component needs to be registered with regasm.exe and it is trying to register it with RegSvr32.  How do I get around this?

Comment: The VB6 ide needs the type library, you did not create one.  Add the /tlb option.

Comment: That was the problem.  (If Hans's comment was not clear, I added "/tbl" on the regasm statement and then the component appeared in VB 6's list of components.)  thanks.